# Approach: python-pdfkit convert webpage(JS generated) into PDF

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, pdfkit

**views.py**

```
def download_as_pdf(request):
    # some stuff/function call to get updated(with data and JS) template and render it

    return render(request, temp)

def download(request):
    import pdfkit
    pdfkit.from_url('/download/', 'out.pdf', options={'ignore-load-errors': None})
    return HttpResponse('DONE')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^download/', views.download_as_pdf, name="download_pdf")
```

I want to print all content(some graphs (JS generated - flotcharts)) of `/download/` url in pdf. If I put these two lines

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('/download/', 'out.pdf', options={'ignore-load-errors': None})
```

in `download_as_pdf` view it prints nothing in pdf (pdf gets download though but empty)
(I think because template rendering happening after these statements thats why ??)

how should I proceed to prit graph in pdf (can I solve this by threading? how?) or any other approach

Comment: Pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf won't handle JS rendering without some changes. Have you tried looking at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949685/create-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-and-rendering-javascript

Answer (score 5):

This could be because pdf is rendered before the entire javascript is loaded. If you introduce a javascript delay it will work.

```
 options = {
    'javascript-delay':'5000'
           }
```

Comment: still printing a blank page for me. the page I am trying to load is a plotly dash website with graphs etc.