# Dash dashboard to PDF: 'loading...' issue

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Good day I've wrote this code in python to convert any website into an PDF:

```
import pdfkit
  
# Define Path of wkhtmltopdf.exe
pathToWkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
  
# Point pdfkit configuration to wkhtmltopdf.exe
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=pathToWkhtmltopdf)
  
# Convert HTML file to PDF File
pdfkit.from_url('http://127.0.0.1:8050/', 'test.pdf', configuration=config)
```

It works perfectly well on any URL I enter into the pdfkit.from_url('<url_path_name>'),
but as soon as I try to render a local dash app it comes out like this:

[image: The dash web frame that is not rendered properly:]

Here is what my test dash app looks like:
[image: My dash dashboard]

and that should be converted into a pdf that should look something this:

[image: This is a test on another website to see if my code is working],

Meanwhile when I use my localhost URL it comes out like this:

[image: Here is the issue]

I'm not sure How to fix this problem. Please note that the pdf that has to be rendered needs to be static and not image based

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39354123/11080037) fix your pb?